# Elastic Search Index Refresh Interval elastic.yaml file in Kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, indexing

I am new to elastic search. I have a 3 data node and 3 master node elastic cluster deployed in Kubernetes. It was working well until recently there is a large intake of data. Now, I am in a stage where I need to apply index refresh interval configuration to 120s to allow optimal usage of the cluster. I am able to do it on individual index level [using this method](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#reset-index-setting). but I am not able to do at the cluster level. I have a process that creates a new index everyday and do not have more than 15 indexes totally at any point of time in the cluster. So, currently, I am doing it manually by using the method afore mentioned/using Kibana UI. I tried to do this couple of ways both failed.

1. Used the settings PUT method to force the index settings at the global level and it gives an error of no requests in the range

`PUT /_cluster/settings -d {      "index" : {        "refresh_interval" : "120s"      }    }`

2. I used the elasticsearch yaml to set this value for the data node and the data node fails to come up.

elasticsearch yaml

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: elastic-cluster
  namespace: elastic-system
spec:
  version: 7.6.2
  nodeSets:
    - name: master
      count: 3
      config:
        node.master: true
        node.data: false
        node.ingest: false
        node.ml: false
        node.store.allow_mmap: false
      podTemplate:
            ...
    - name: data1
      count: 3
      config:
        node.master: false
        node.data: true
        node.ingest: true
        node.ml: false
        node.store.allow_mmap: false
        index.refresh_interval: 120s # I added it here
      podTemplate:
            ...
```

There is a third way, through kibana UI -> settings-> Elastic Search -> Index management -> index template. But there is no index template for me to start with. Nevertheless, the elastic search creates an index daily with the date. So, I do not want to mess with the existing template.

Can anyone suggest me a better way to do this

Comment: Why not create a new index template?

Comment: Yes, I can do it based on existing index and its data.(last resort) I am wondering how the existing index is created in the first place without a template and I am not sure if it impacts the current daily creation of index when this index template is created. Index name starts with logstash-**(date here).

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is to create an index template that applies default settings when an index is created.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html

Old indexes are not affected by this template - only new ones.

If you don't want to create a template, you have to set the refresh interval manually.

You can try setting index settings with a wildcard like this:
`PUT /my-index-2022-*/_settings`

`/_cluster/settings` has no relation to index settings - it's configuration settings for the cluster, so don't try to do index operations with that URL.

The same applies to the YAML file - the configuration there has no relationship with the index settings.